# How to make a Dynamic Line Graph in PHP - Mysql

Tags: php, graph, phpgraphlib

I want to make a dynamic line graph in php with mysql data. Please verify my **Attached Image** [image]

How to get this type of graph ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443720/how-to-create-graph-from-php-mysql-data

Comment: Did you draw it with your hand?

Comment: Yes .  for the Reference i draw this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial to plot graphs using Google visualisation.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example

If you want to make it dynamic, you have to use AJAX to call a function in PHP which updates the graph every x seconds. To do that, update the function the following way

```
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({url: "getData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false


    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 1000);
```

This will repeat the call every 1 second. As the setIntervals second parameter is in Milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . But I want a graph like my above image.